# Default initialization of std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, default-constructor, stdarray

With C++11 `std::array`, do I have the guarantee that the syntax `std::array<T, N> x;` will default-initialize all the elements of the array ?

**EDIT**: if not, is there a syntax that will work on all arrays (including zero-sized arrays) to initialize all elements to their default value?

**EDIT**: on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), the default constructor description says:

```
(constructor) (implicitly declared) (public member function)
default-constructs or copy-constructs every element of the array
```

so the answer may be yes. But I would like to be sure of that according to the standard or future standard.

Comment: Don't think so. It's default declared so it's basically the equivalent of the `T x[N]` syntax.

Answer (score 218, accepted):

By definition, default initialization is the initialization that occurs when no other initialization is specified; the C++ language guarantees you that *any* object for which you do not provide an explicit initializer will be default initialized (C++11 §8.5/11). That includes objects of type `std::array<T, N>` and `T[N]`.

Be aware that there are types for which default initialization has no effect and leaves the object's value indeterminate: any non-class, non-array type (§8.5/6). Consequently, a default-initialized array of objects with such types will have indeterminate value, e.g.:

```
int plain_int;
int c_style_array[13];
std::array<int, 13> cxx_style_array;
```

Both the c-style array and `std::array` are filled with integers of indeterminate value, just as `plain_int` has indeterminate value.

> Is there a syntax that will work on all arrays (including zero-sized arrays) to initialize all elements to their default value?

I'm guessing that when you say "to their default value" you really mean "initialize all elements to `T{}`". That's not *default-initialization*, it is *value-initialization* (8.5/7). You can request value initialization quite easily in C++11 by giving each declaration an empty initializer:

```
int plain_int{};
int c_style_array[13]{};
std::array<int, 13> cxx_style_array{};
```

Which will value-initialize all of the array elements in turn, resulting in `plain_int`, and all the members of both kinds of arrays, being initialized to zero.

Comment: What about if it's a class member:
    struct X {
      std::array<int,12> dozen;
       X( )
         :dozen( ) {}
Does that get me twelve zeros?

Comment: @gerardw According to the standard, yes it does. Beware bugs in MSVC, it fails to implement some cases of value initialization correctly.

Comment: indeed boost says so and workaround it with their `boost::value_initialized`  [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm) but I believe VC12 (VS2013) has a much better support now.

Comment: Makes me wish the comitee changed the standard to default value-initialization and undermined value at request. Ie std::array<int, 12> = {std::undetermined}; or something

Comment: In practice what does it even mean to initialize something to an indeterminate value? What's the alternative?

Comment: @Andrew The alternative is that it does something other than initialising it to a defined value.  Basically the compiler is free to do whatever is convenient.  In practice this often means that in debug mode you'll get a specific weird not-zero value and in release mode you'll get whatever garbage happened to be left in that stack space from some other function (or occasionally zero by coincidence) -- ie. the compiler simply doesn't initialise at all.  As for why you'd ever want that: it's faster -- as long as you promise you'll write some other value before you try to read it.

Comment: @Casey, what does mean `plain_old_int`?

Comment: @user It's an error; `plain_int` was intended. Fixed.

Comment: @gerardw What's struct X { std::array<int,12> dozen; X( ) :dozen( ) {}? clerical error?

Comment: @Casey Any difference between `char myarray[ARRAY_SIZE] {0};` and `char myarray[ARRAY_SIZE] {};`?

Comment: @Casey As you say "there are types for which default initialization has no effect and leaves the object's value indeterminate: any non-class, ***non-array*** type (§8.5/6)."   But `int c_style_array[13];` is **array**, why its "default initialization has no effect"?

Answer (score 36):

*Default-initialization* is a term from the Standard potentially meaning no initialization at all, so you probably mean *zero-initialization*.

The description at cppreference.com is actually a bit misleading. `std::array` is an aggregate class, and if the element type is primitive, it is POD: "plain old data," with semantics closely matching the C language. The implicitly-defined constructor of `std::array< int, N >` is a *trivial* one which does absolutely nothing.

Syntax like `std::array< int, 3 >()` or `std::array< int, 3 > x{}` which provide zeroed values do not do so by invoking a constructor. Getting zeroes is part of *value-initialization*, specified in C++11 §8.5/8:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized …, and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;

`std::array` has no user-provided default constructor, so it gets zero-initialized. It has an implicitly-defined default constructor, but it is trivial, so it is never default-initialized. (But this doesn't make a difference since trivial initialization by definition has no effect at runtime.)

> if not, is there a syntax that will work on all arrays (including zero-sized arrays) to initialize all elements to their default value?

C-style arrays and `std::array` are both aggregates, and the way to completely zero-initialize any aggregate is with the syntax `= {}`. This works since C++98. Note that C-style arrays cannot have zero extent, and that `sizeof (std::array< X, 0 >)` is not zero.

Comment: “Syntax like std::array< int, 3 >() or std::array< int, 3 > x{} which provide zeroed values **do not do so by invoking a constructor**.” What's that? What do you intend to tell us?Could you please explain that in more detail?

Answer (score 15):

Both `T x[N];` and `std::array<T, N> x;` default-initialize every element of the array.

For example, if `T = std::string`, every element will be an empty string. If `T` is a class without a default constructor, both will fail to compile. If `T = int`, every element will have indeterminate value (unless that declaration happens to be at namespace scope)

Comment: Your example is very explanatory, and should be part of the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

C++11 [std::array::fill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/fill/) is a good option for some cases.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, T x[N] does default initialize the elements, although default initialization of a scalar type T actually does nothing. The above also holds for std::array x. I think what you need is list initialization.