# "Default constructor cannot be referenced" errormessage - is using a default constructor mandatory in my case? (Learning OOP)

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

class Deck;

class Card
{
public:
    enum cRanks
    {
        RANK_2,
        RANK_3,
        RANK_4,
        RANK_5,
        RANK_6,
        RANK_7,
        RANK_8,
        RANK_9,
        RANK_10,
        RANK_J,
        RANK_Q,
        RANK_K,
        RANK_A,

        MAX_RANKS,
        RANK_AIR
    };

    enum cSuits
    {
        SUIT_CLUBS,
        SUIT_DIAMONDS,
        SUIT_HEARTS,
        SUIT_SPADES,

        MAX_SUITS,
        SUIT_AIR
    };

private:
    cRanks m_rank{RANK_A};
    cSuits m_suit{SUIT_SPADES};

public:
    //Card() = default;

    Card(cRanks r, cSuits s)
        :m_rank{ r }, m_suit{ s }
    {
    }

    void print() const
    {
        char rank{};
        char suit{};
        switch (m_rank)
        {
            case(RANK_2): rank = '2'; break;
            case(RANK_3): rank = '3'; break;
            case(RANK_4): rank = '4'; break;
            case(RANK_5): rank = '5'; break;
            case(RANK_6): rank = '6'; break;
            case(RANK_7): rank = '7'; break;
            case(RANK_8): rank = '8'; break;
            case(RANK_9): rank = '9'; break;
            case(RANK_10): rank = 't'; break;
            case(RANK_J): rank = 'J'; break;
            case(RANK_Q): rank = 'Q'; break;
            case(RANK_K): rank = 'K'; break;
            case(RANK_A): rank = 'A'; break;
            case(RANK_AIR): rank = '_'; break;
            default: rank = '?';
        }
        switch (m_suit)
        {
            case(SUIT_CLUBS): suit = 'C'; break;
            case(SUIT_DIAMONDS): suit = 'D'; break;
            case(SUIT_HEARTS): suit = 'H'; break;
            case(SUIT_SPADES): suit = 'S'; break;
            case(SUIT_AIR): suit = '_'; break;
            default: suit = '?';
        }
        std::cout << rank << suit << ' ';
    }

    friend Deck; 
};

class Deck
{
public:
    using array_type = std::array<Card, 52>;
    using index_type = int;
private:
    array_type m_deck;
    index_type m_index{ 0 };

public:
    Deck()
    {
        m_index = 0;
        int index{0};
        for (int s{ 0 }; s < Card::MAX_SUITS; ++s)
        {
            for (int r{ 0 }; r < Card::MAX_RANKS; ++r)
            {
                m_deck[index].m_rank = static_cast<Card::cRanks>(r);
                m_deck[index].m_suit = static_cast<Card::cSuits>(s);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        if (m_index > static_cast<int>(m_deck.size()) - 1)
        {
            std::cout << "\nDeck out of cards!";
            return;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        for (int i{ m_index }; i < m_deck.size(); ++i)
            m_deck[i].print();
    }

    void shuffle(unsigned int seed = 777)
    {
        std::mt19937 g{ seed };
        std::shuffle(m_deck.begin(), m_deck.end(), g);
    }

    const Card& draw()
    {
        if (m_index > static_cast<int>(m_deck.size()) - 1)
        {
            std::cout << "\nDeck out of cards!";
            return Card(Card::RANK_AIR, Card::SUIT_AIR);
        }
        return m_deck[m_index++];
    }
};

int main()
{
    Deck deck{};
    deck.print();
    deck.shuffle();
    deck.print();



    return 0;
}
```

Simple BlackJack game-exercise to learn OOP. In the above code I get the error message "the default constructor of cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function" on my Deck constructor. Is it wise to assume that my m_deck array cannot be instantiated so that the constructor of Deck can assign values to it because the Card class has no default constructor? What if I want my default Card constructor to have arguments? Can I avoid using "Cards() = default;" in my Cards class? I was thinking that it is only sensible to instantiate a Card object only if you define it's nature (rank and suit).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295302/default-initialization-of-stdarray) might give you an answer, though I'm not sure it answers your specific case as clearly as I'd like. If you have questions after reading that, perhaps edit your question.

Comment: You need the default constructor to initialize the elements of the array or you have to provide the necessary arguments with [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)(which replaces the need for the nested `for` loops). There are a other alternatives, but [they get weird.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no recipe to construct an object of Card() from the returning type const Card& in the absence of the copy constructor; constexpr Card::Card(const Card&)
2. The compiler would like to use default constructor provided by you
   or generated by it to match the return type Card in std::array. Hence, 
   `/usr/include/c++/7/array:94:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Card::Card()`
3. I tried to replicate your code with bare minimum things with
   addition of 
    `Card() = default; Card(const Card& other) = default;` 
   It seems to be compiling at least. I can't check functional aspects for
   you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class Deck;

class Card
{
public:
    enum cRanks
    {
        RANK_A,
        MAX_RANKS,
        RANK_AIR
    };

    enum cSuits
    {
        SUIT_SPADES,
        MAX_SUITS,
        SUIT_AIR
    };
private:
    cRanks m_rank{RANK_A};
    cSuits m_suit{SUIT_SPADES};

public:
    Card() = default;

    Card(const Card& other) = default;

    Card(cRanks r, cSuits s)
        :m_rank{ r }, m_suit{ s }
    {
    }

    void print() const
    {
        char rank{};
        char suit{};
        switch (m_rank)
        {
            case(RANK_A): rank = '_'; break;
            default: rank = '?';
        }
        switch (m_suit)
        {
            case(SUIT_SPADES): suit = 'C'; break;
            default: suit = '?';
        }
        std::cout << rank << suit << ' ';
    }

    friend Deck; 
};

class Deck
{
public:
    using array_type = std::array<Card, 52>;
    using index_type = int;
private:
    array_type m_deck;
    index_type m_index{ 0 };

public:
    Deck()
    {
    }

    void print()
    {
    }

    void shuffle(unsigned int seed = 777)
    {
    }

    const Card& draw()
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    Deck deck{};
    deck.print();
    deck.shuffle();
    deck.print();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first point is incorrect. While I generally recommend `Card(const Card& other) = default;` as you've done in the code example to be brutally explicit, noting here is preventing the compiler from auto-generating a defaulted copy constructor without prompting. What `constexpr` adds to the operation is not clear. You should explain that a bit more.

Comment: In the second point, the wording is confusing. `Card` is not a return type, and this makes the explanation of what went wrong hard to follow.

Comment: the third point deflects the question. The questioner was wondering if there was a way, other than `Card() = default;`, to make their code work. You do not address this.

Comment: You suggested in your answer that the user of this code either need the default constructor to initialize the elements of the array or some other way to get around. I think the user of this class has to decide between your answer and their choice of not providing a default constructor, even though I would like the rationale behind it.