# Value-initialization of std::array inside std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, initialization

Consider the code:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
int main () {
        std::unordered_map<int, std::array<int, 5>> map;
        map[42][0] = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                std::cout << map[42][i] << " ";
        }
}
```

This prints `1 0 0 0 0` on my system.  The content of `std::array` held inside `std::map` was value-initialized upon insertion (i.e. all integers inside array were set to 0). Does the standard guarantee this? I should never expect the array used as value of the map to contain garbage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default initialization of std::array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295302/default-initialization-of-stdarray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

operator [] inserts `value_type(key, T())` if the key does not exist. This function is equivalent to `return insert(std::make_pair(key, T()))`

T() means default initialization

since c++17
This function is equivalent to return `this->try_emplace(key).first->second`

emplace/try_emplace constructs default-initalized value in case of  operator []

from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: you are quoting from the pre-c++11 part of the reference. Though answer is same

Comment: @idclev463035818 thanks. added to the answer

Comment: fwiw if I understood the note about LWG issue 2469 correctly, what you had first is actually what is in the published c++11 and c++14 standards

Comment: But default initialization on an array of primitive type doesn't actually provide default initialize items inside. `std::array<int, 5> arr` would give indeterminate values. You have to do a zero init to it

Comment: @Ranoiaetep array behaves just like int. pls compare ```int a```. and ```int a{}```. the behavior of array is the same. map forces the default initialization to 0.

Comment: This answers my question, but T() does not mean default-initilization, it means value-initialization, at least since C++03 (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization)

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't quite convincing. However found better explanation in the ISO n4835 draft:  9.4.0.7: To default-initialize an object of type T means:' 9.4.0.7.2: If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized'

Comment: @lukeg that works, per ISO n4835 draft: 9.4.0.8: To value-initialize an object of type T means:' 9.4.0.8.3: If T is an array type, each element is value-initialized'