# Memset warning treated as error, based on its thrd argument

Tags: c++, makefile, build, automake, memset

When built without `AM_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-memset-elt-size` on the AutoMake Makefile, i get this error:

`error: ‘memset’ used with length equal to number of elements without multiplication by element size [-Werror=memset-elt-size] memset (_floatOptions, 0, sizeof(_floatOptions));`

This is the line that triggers it:
`memset (_floatOptions, 0, sizeof(_floatOptions));`

And this is the relevant code:

```
class random_class
{
  public:
    enum FloatOption
    {
        numFloatOptions
    };
    
    /// Set a float option value
    /// @param f Float Option
    /// @param value value to be set
    void setFloatValue(FloatOption f, double value)
    {
        _floatOptions[f] = value; 
        _isSetFloat[f] = true;
    }

    /// Return value of an float option
    /// @param f Float Option
    /// @return HostPlacement
    double getFloatValue(FloatOption f) const
    {
        return _floatOptions[f];
    }

  private:
    double  _floatOptions[numFloatOptions];
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can mitigate it?

I couldn't find much info on this warning/error online.

Comment: `numFloatOptions` will be equal to `0`. You can't have zero-sized arrays. And where do you use `memset`? Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, because right now you show quite a lot of irrelevant things, while not showing us the actual code causing the error.

Comment: @user1584421, Post the code that uses `memset (_floatOptions, 0, sizeof(_floatOptions));`.

Comment: This looks like a false positive (because 0 is simultaneously the number of elements and the size) and will go away once you add at least one option.

Comment: @molbdnilo Disagree with [sizeof(_floatOptions) is not the number of elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77541921/memset-warning-treated-as-error-based-on-its-thrd-argument#comment136702144_77541921).  The array size is 0 and the number of elements is 0.

Comment: Why are you using `memset` anyway? If you [value-initialize `_floatOptions`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18295840/1548468) in your constructor every float will be zeroed by the compiler.